# How to change today's column color in Angular calendar

Tags: angular

I am using [angular calendar](https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-calendar) and I am trying to change today's column color but it does not have an identifier to do it with CSS.

Any idea?

[image: Angular calendar]

Comment: Hi do you found any solution for this actually i am also looking for the solution

Comment: No, I had to change and use fullcalendar instead.